# Automatically manipulating argument for Mongoose Document constructor

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Let's say I have have this model:

```js
const employeeSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      age: Number,
      employeeData: {
        department: String,
        position: String,
        lastTraining: Date
      }
});

const Employee = mongoose.model('employee', employeeSchema);
```

In the database, the only thing that is going to be saved is something that looks like this:

```js
{
  _id: ...
  name: 'John Smith',
  age: 40,
  employeeCode: '.... '
}
```

What's going on is that by some business rules, the employeeData info, which is coming from the reqeust body, is going through some function that compiles out of it the employeeCode, and when saving to the database I just use to the employeeCode.

Right now, the way I am implementing this is using statics. So, I have in the model the follwing:

```js
employeeSchema.statics.compileEmployeeCode = (doc) => {
  if (!doc.employeeData) {
    doc.employeeCode= compileCode(doc.employeeData);
    delete doc.employeeData;
  }
  
  return doc;
}
```

And then, I need to remember, for each call that receives info from the client, to call this function before creating the document (an instance of the model):

```js
const compiledDoc = Employee.compileEmployeeCode(req.body);
const employee = new Employee(comiledDoc);
```

My question is: is there a way to automatically invoke some function that compiles the code out of the data any time I create a document like that, so I won't need to remember to always call on the static method beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

[Middlaware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) is what you are looking for. You need to create a function that will set a pre-save hook on the schema (which will be triggered every time before saving a new document) and to plug this function into the schema.

```
function compileEmployeeCode (schema) {
  schema.pre('save', next => {
    if (this.employeeData) {
      this.employeeCode= compileCode(this.employeeData);
      delete this.employeeData;

      next();
    }
  });
}

employeeSchema.plugin(compileEmployeeCode);
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. So, in this case, the 'this' would actually refer to the document? I thought that with the new arrow functions the 'this' keyword behaves differently...

Comment: Yes, this refers to a document instance

Comment: Cool. Thank you.

Comment: OK. This is totally not working. First I cannot use this with an arrow function, but that's a minor problem. The real issue is that I simply not able to just change the document represented in this and have it changed in the database. It looks like I cannot make changes that change the layout of the actual schema. Mongoose simply ignores these and saves the schema as it was originally defined. I need the schema to represent how the data looks like in the database, not in the request, and find some hook to modify the data right before creating an instance of a model from it.

Answer (score 0):

OK. It was really hard but I finally managed to find the solution. The trick is to use a setter on a specific path. Each field in the schema is of type SchemaType which can have a setter apply on it:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-set

Anyway, if I want to make it possible for the request to enter an object that will be converted to some other format, say a string, I would need to define the schema like this:

```js
const employeeSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      age: Number,
      employeeCode: {
        type: String,
        set: setCodeFromObj,
        alias: 'employeeData'
      }
});
```

The setter function I'm using here looks something like this (I'm omitting here all the error handling and the like to keep this short:

```js
function setCodeFromObj(v) {
  const obj = {};
  obj.department = v.department;
  obj.position = v.position;
  obj.lastTraining = v.lastTraing
  // breaking the object to properties just to show that v actually includes them
  
  return compileEmployeeCode(obj);
}
```

I used an alias to make the name visible to the user different from what is actually saved in the database. I could have also done that using virtuals or just design the system a bit differently to use up the same name.